# How do I mock selectors in nrgx 8 unit tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ngrx

I am learning to write unit tests for ngrx8 application using Jest.

I am testing a component that has subscription to a selector in ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.pipe(select(someSelector(this.parameter))).subscribe((res: 
    // some logic here
  });
}
```

In the .spec.ts file I put `provideMockStore` in TestBed configuration:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
      provideMockStore({
        initialState, // defined somewhere above
        selectors: [
          {
            selector: someSelector('param'),
            value: {a: 'b', c: 'd'}
          }
        ]
      })
    ]
    // ...
}).compileComponents();;
```

So I expect that while running this unit test, I should enter the subscription (the "some logic here" section) in the component .ts file and `res` will equal `{a: 'b', c: 'd'}`.

That doesn't happen, instead mocked selector is ignored and the real one is used.

Things I tried:

- `store.overrideSelector(someSelector('param'), {a: 'b', c: 'd')`
- Putting `fixture.detectChanges()`, `await fixture.whenStable()`, in different places

Now I am out of options, and the [NGRX documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors) doesn't cover almost anything.

Comment: life without ngrx facades is hard... I would suggest you do some refactor and use facades. it makes testing components a breeze, as you can separate the store mocking from the component dependency mocking.

Answer (score 3):

Mocking the selector doesn't seem to be the best solution.
It would be better to mock the store itself.

You can provide the state in :

```
provideMockStore({ initialState: your_state })
```

or

```
mockStore.setState(your_state);
```

`mockStore.setState(...)` allows you to do tests with different value in your store inside your tests.

**BUT** I suggest you do do the following if you have a complex store:

- create a class where you will have your mock store state: `MockStoreState`.

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
  T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
    T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
      T[P];
};

export class MockStoreState {
  private store_a: RecursivePartial<Store_A>;
  private store_b: RecursivePartial<Store_b>;

  build(): any {
    const defaultStore_a = {
      ...
    };
    const defaultStore_b = {
      ...
    };

    return {
      store_a: { ...defaultStore_a , ...this.store_a},
      store_b: { ...defaultStore_b , ...this.store_b },
    };
  }

  setStore_a(value: RecursivePartial<Store_A>): Store_A_State {
    this.store_a= value;
    return this;
  }

  setStore_b(value: RecursivePartial<DatasourceState>): Store_B_State {
    this.store_b= value;
    return this;
  }
}
```

- Set the state in your store in the test:

```
describe(MyComponent.name, () => {
   ...
   let mockStore: MockStore<any>;

   beforeEach(() => {
       ...
       mockStore = TestBed.get(Store);
   })


   it('...', () => {
     const state = new MockStoreState().setStore_a({...})
    .build();

    mockStore.setState(state);

   // HERE you have set the data in your store.
   })
}
```

Comment: I am trying the first solution you proposed. It works if I set the state before first ```fixture.detectChanges``` But setting state after first ```fixture.detectChanges()``` doesn't fire any subscriptions - so I cannot test if the component responds to state changes. Do I need to manually run some function so I can do that?