# Angular Ngrx Test: Store.overrideSelector does not override

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx, angular-test

I do have the following `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ApplyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    store = TestBed.get<Store<fromAnnouncement.AnnouncementState>>(Store);
    store.refreshState();
    mockApplicationSelector = store.overrideSelector(selectDraftApplication, testDraftApplication); <-- Try to mock  a selector here.
  });
```

The selector selectDraftApplication depends on the feature selector for the `AnnouncementState`, which has two entities in it, one of which im subselecting with a feature selector in order to build my `selectDraftApplication` selector.

When using this code in test, all my tests crash, because NgRx somehow still seems to look for all the state further up, when I would expect a mock to be something that prevents precisely this. There is no point in mocking out a whole ngrx entity store, so I would just like the selector to return exactly that object and be done with it. I googled wide and far, but did not get any answer. Any help? I run Angular 8 and ngrx 8.5.1 (the `refreshState()` function did not work either...)

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

```
export const getAnnouncementState = createFeatureSelector<AnnouncementState>('announcement');

export const getApplicationsState = createSelector(
  getAnnouncementState,
  (state: AnnouncementState) => state.applications 
);

export const selectDraftApplication = createSelector(
  getApplicationsState,
  (state: ApplicationState) => state.draftApplication
);
```

Comment: How does the selector look like?

Comment: Hi @timdeschryver. I added the selector chain. The tests break at the second one, where applications is selected (which does not exist, as I would have to mock out an ngrx entity for doing that). All I am interested in is selecting a draftApplication

Comment: That should work imho, if you have a reproduction I'm happy to take a look

Comment: There was the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787505/how-do-i-mock-selectors-in-nrgx-8-unit-tests/58787732#58787732. (quick answer, I don't think that mocking the selector is the best idea, but here is alternative)

Comment: Thanks @Wandrille. I am halfway down this path, where I set the selector directly in the MockStore, and do an override when I need it. I read several times now that mocking a selector is not the best idea. Why is that? For this Unit test, I am only interested in returning a proper value, which is checked for type by TypeScript so I can unit test my component. I wouldn't mock it if I'd test the selector itself, but what's wrong about it in this case?

Comment: Selector are nothing more than constant for mapping (`export const mySelector = createSelector(mySate, (state) => state.foo);`). And you don't mock constant,  don't you. In unit test, you are tying to mock the result of particular methods. With NGRX, the easiest way to expect content from methods is to populate the store (that is nothing more than an object for the test). **BUT** Another alternative, can be to have your store inside a service and then, you can mock your service inside your component.

Comment: Please, stop writing, that overriding selector is not a good idea. It's just like setting an input for the test. The purest unit test. If you don't need testing the state integration this the best approach!

Answer (score 6):

You need to call `refreshState()` after mocking the selector...

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ApplyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    store = TestBed.get<Store<fromAnnouncement.AnnouncementState>>(Store);
    //
    mockApplicationSelector = store.overrideSelector(selectDraftApplication, testDraftApplication); <-- Try to mock  a selector here.

    store.refreshState(); <-- refresh state ***after*** mocking the selector
  });
```

Comment: seems that sometimes it works without it, sometime it doesn't