# Testing selectors on real store with observables in ngrx

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I want to write a test that checks if dispatched actions correctly modify the state and as a result selectors emit new values. For the sake of the question, I've created this simple example:

1. I dispatch `updateDateOfBirth` that updates state
2. I want to test if selector emits a new value
3. To do it, I've created a subscription and I'm collecting all emitted values and then I compare it to expected sequence

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { sectionOneFeatureKey } from './section-one.reducer';
import { getReducer } from './section-one.reducer';
import { StoreModule, Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { getDateOfBirth } from './section-one.selectors';
import { State } from './section-one.state';
import { updateDateOfBirth } from './section-one.actions';

fdescribe('section-one selectors', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({ [sectionOneFeatureKey]: getReducer() })]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should react to store changes', () => {
    const store: Store<State> = TestBed.get(Store);
    const result = [];
    store.pipe(select(getDateOfBirth)).subscribe(x => result.push(x));
    store.dispatch(updateDateOfBirth({ value: 'one' }));
    store.dispatch(updateDateOfBirth({ value: 'two' }));

    // slice(1) to skip initial value
    expect(result.slice(1)).toEqual(['one', 'two']);
  });
});
```

This solution with collecting via subscribe & `push` works, however, I wonder if there's a more elegant way, something like with `provideMockActions`. I tried to use it, but apparently actions were not dispatched automatically to the store (this works only with effects). Also when I move subscription to last line in the test then I get only last value. I also tried to use `toMatchObservable` but the effect was the same: I still receive only last emitted value:

```
expect(store.pipe(select(getDateOfBirth))).toMatchObservable(....)
```

Is there a better way to write this kind of test?

Comment: See my answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787505/how-do-i-mock-selectors-in-nrgx-8-unit-tests/58787732#58787732

Answer (score 0):

Selectors are pure functions. You can invoke them as how you would any other function and see how their results change as state changes. (Note this for V7 of NGRX! V8 testing got a lot easier: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#testing-selectors)

```
// here I have a function that creates a mock store for me
const createMockStore = (state = initialState) => action => ({
  [SOME_FEATURE_KEY]: someReducer(state, action)
});

describe('SomeFeatureSelectors', () => {
  let storeFactory;

  beforeEach(() => {
    storeFactory = createMockStore(initialState);
  });

  describe('mySelectors', () => {
    it(`should return the error text and set isLoading to false`, () => {
      const state = storeFactory(new fromFeatureActions.SomeActivationFailure('ERROR'));
      const error = fromFeatureQuery.getActivationFailure(state);
      const isLoading = fromFeatureQuery.getActivationLoading(state);
      expect(error).toEqual('ERROR');
      expect(isLoading).toEqual(false);
    });
  });
```

You can then "update" your state by invoking your reducer with a new action and previous state. Then you can run your selectors again and examine changes.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have questions.